# Show related post link title

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

For a portfolio case study page I've setup 'related_post' in ACF using page link.

At present I'm using the following which correctly shows the full URL as I'd expect.

```
<p><a href="{{post.get_field('related_post')}}" target="_blank">{{post.get_field('related_post')}}</a></p>
```

Instead I want to show the related post title.  I've looked at the Timber ACF cookbook but all the alternatives, in terms of syntax, I've tried don't work.

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use post object field instead of page link, as this will store all the information in regards to the post in an array and will contain the url and page title?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [heady12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4624719/heady12) changing the field type to Post Object from Page Link in ACF allowed me to show the title using the following.

```
<p><a href="{{post.get_field('related_post').link}}">{{post.get_field('related_post').title}}</a></p>
```

Thanks for your help